# Sequence of Cohen-Macaulay subschemes and regular embedding

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complete-intersection

Let $X$ be a non-singular variety, $Y_1, Y_2$ be non-singular subvarieties of 
$X$ of the same dimension such that $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is non-singular, irreducible and $Y_1 \cup Y_2$ is a local complete intersection subscheme in $X$.  Is $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ a local complete intersection subscheme in $Y_1 \cup Y_2$?

Comment: Let $X = \mathbf{A}^2$, and let $Y_i$ be the two axes. Then $Y_1 \cup Y_2$ is lci and $Y_1 \cap Y_2$ is non-singular (it is the origin regarded as a reduced scheme). But the origin inside the union of the two axes is not an lci subscheme. Indeed, this follows by observing that the $k[x,y]/(xy)$-module $k[x,y]/(xy,x,y) =~ k$ has infinite projective dimension (by computing Tors against itself).

Comment: More generally, for any $X$, if $Y_1\cap Y_2$ is a single (reduced) point, then it will never be an lci subscheme in $Y_1\cup Y_2$, because if it were, then its maximal ideal would be generated by $d=\dim Y_1=\dim Y_2$ elements, which would imply that it is a regular point of $Y_1\cup Y_2$, but it obviously isn't.